# Using python to delete objects in AutoCAD document

Tags: python, autocad, comtypes

I'm struggling with developing a code that will delete objects/blocks in AutoCAD. I'm using the code posted by the user, mortbauer:

```
import array 
import comtypes.client
app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
ms = app.ActiveDocument
files = r"C:\Users\TOM\Desktop\02python\516.00-501.50.dwg"
insertionPnt = array.array('d', [0,0,0]) 
ms.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, files, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

I used the erase command from AutoCAD and replaced it erase (in this world, nothing is this easy). It didn't cause an error, but it didn't do anything.

```
ms.ModelSpace.erase
```

I believe there is a selection of the objects before the erase command would work. However, this is what I'm struggling with. I've tried select and selection. But I just get attribute errors.

Comment: most commands in autocad from the command line are command followed by selection.  some orignal commands you can still select objects first then do the command, but this is not always the case.